# Docker exec command is failing with EXIT CODE 137

Tags: docker, exit-code, docker-exec

I am running a CICD pipeline that runs a test script inside a docker container with docker exec and its failing with a return code of 137 every 3rd or 4th time. Here is the code that's running:

```
docker-compose -p 1234 -f docker-compose.yml exec -T webapp run_tests.sh
STATUS=$?
...
docker-compose -p 1234 -f docker-compose.yml logs --no-color webapp
...
exit $STATUS
```

Thing is whenever it fails with EXIT CODE 137, container gets killed immediately and there are no logs available for debugging. I think 137 is caused by some external process but I am not able to trace it. Any insights into this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question, I experience a related error and it was related to a memory limit, try to increase your swap memory.
Here a link with someone with [similar problem](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1177)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I experience related error too, in my case i got error when executing docker-compose exec on my Jenkins build. Fixed by add `deploy` config to `docker-compose.yaml` to increase memory limit

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: my-app:1.0.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile 
    # ports: 
    # networks: 
    # volumes: 
    # depends_on: 
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500M
        reservations:
          memory: 128M
```

Try changing `deploy.resources.limits.memory` and `deploy.resources.reservations.memory`

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#resources